# set encoding utf-8 for ksoap2 in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have problem with ksoap2, i want set encoding utf-8 for ksoap2 in android, or set content-type in header is text/xml,charset=utf=8,
my code:
//set encoding

```
envelope.encodingStyle = "utf-8";
```

//set header

```
envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();

private Element buildAuthHeader() {
    String namesc = "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap";
    Log.i("---build--","--buildAuthHeader--->");
    Element h = new Element().createElement(namesc, "Headers");
    Element username = new Element().createElement(namesc, "Content-Type");
    username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);

    return h;
}
```

but not work. please help me.
thanks.

Comment: which error you are geting.

Comment: for ksoap2 we use the 4 variables.1- namespace 2-url 3- target namespace 4- method name, and then use this variable in your class file.

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is done like so:

```
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, TIME_OUT);
transport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
```